# Checking for empty queryset in Python/MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I can't seem to find a simple answer for this question. I am using MySQLdb for Python and I am running a select statement, I want to check if an empty query set is returned.

```
get_port = db.cursor()
get_port.execute(""" SELECT port FROM nar_ports WHERE port=%s AND hostname=%s;""", (device_port,PE))
```

I have tried

```
if not get_port:
```

This doesn't match. So then I tried

```
for result in get_port.fetchall():
    existing_port = result[0]
if not existing_port:
```

But it doesn't even seem to enter the loop. So then I tried to check the length

```
if len(get_port) == 0:
```

But it seems you can't run len on a sql object. So I check if the object has a none value.

```
if get_port = None:
```

But this doesn't seem to work either.

I'm certain there is a simple solution for this but I cannot seem to find it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple, though you almost had a longer way.

```
if get_port.fetchone():
    do_something_here()
```

You could also have used

```
if len(get_port.fetchmany()):
    do_something_here()
```

But that is longer and less efficient.

Comment: Hey Pydsigner, man I was so close, dam! lol. Thank you for your response, that worked. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem! It's a pleasure to help people who have already done so much to help themselves. BTW, you can accept and/or upvote my answer, which will help other helpful people from coming in to answer your question again.

Comment: Thank you and the same to you.